# Save Holoviews as interactive html

Tags: python, pandas, holoviews

I have a Holoviews code with the intent of saving the output as .html. The below works fine i.e. html is genereated and tags are renders but filters don't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
def load_data(country, lan_name, **kwargs):
    df = subset
    if country != 'ALL':
        df = df[(df.country == country)]
    if lan_name != 'ALL':
        df = df[(df.lan_name == lan_name)]

    table = format_chars(df['term'], df['hex'])
    #hv.Table(df, ['country', 'lan_name'], [], label='Data Table')

    layout = (table).opts(
        opts.Layout(merge_tools=False),
        opts.Div(width=700, height=400),
    )
    return layout

methods = ['ALL'] + sorted(list(subset['country'].unique()))
models = ['ALL'] + sorted(list(subset['lan_name'].unique()))
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(load_data, kdims=['country', 'lan_name']).redim.values(country=methods, lan_name=models)
hv.save(dmap, 'output.html', backend='bokeh')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "filters" it sounds like you mean the widgets that select along the `country` and `lan_name` dimensions. Each time you select a new value of a widget, a DynamicMap calls the Python function that you provide it (`load_data` here) to calculate the display (which is what makes it "Dynamic").  There is no Python process available when you have a static HTML file, so the display will never get updated in that case.

To make some limited functionality available in a static HTML file, you can convert the DynamicMap to a HoloMap that contains all the displayed items for some specific combinations of widget values (http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Live_Data.html#Converting-from-DynamicMap-to-HoloMap).  The resulting parameter space can quickly get quite large, so you will often need to select a feasible subset of values for this to be a practical option.